# Можно вызвать элементы из одной функции в другой?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Я приведу пример на простых функциях:

```
def first():
    a = '1'
    b = '2'
    c = '3'
    print(a,b,c)

def second():
    lst = []
    lst.append(a)
    lst.append(b)
    lst.append(c)
    return lst
```

Я понимаю, что этот код выдает ошибку, поэтому вопрос:
каким способом можно сделать то, что я написал выше, или в питоне вообще нельзя брать элементы в функциях из других функций.

Если все же так делать нельзя, я был бы очень рад, если бы вы предложили какое-то альтернативное решение

Спасибо

Comment: Не берусь утверждать, но окружение функции убирается после исполнения. Поэтому без передачи параметров сделать ничего нельзя.

Comment: Оформите код нормально. Непонятно в чём проблема. Я вижу, что такой код должен работать нормально.

Comment: @МистерФикс оформил, видимо подразумевается вызов `first()` потом вызов `second()`

Comment: @МистерФикс, очевидно что не будет. В `second` не будет переменных `a`, `b`, `c`, что выкинет ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну раз такое дело, то да. Функция не видит, того, что находится в другой функции если она не вложенная. То есть она может видеть переменные только во вмещающей её области.

```
def first():
    a = '1'
    b = '2'
    c = '3'
    print(a,b,c)

    def second():
        lst = []
        lst.append(a)
        lst.append(b)
        lst.append(c)
        return lst
    second()
```

Comment: А зачем тут тогда `second` нужна?

Comment: Это просто пример работы областей видимости. Вас ведь это интересовало?

Comment: Я знаю как это работает, но тут функция лишняя. Как демо замыканий - пойдёт.

Comment: А, извиняюсь. С автором перепутал :)

Comment: Извините, но теперь проблема в том, что вне первой функции я не могу вызвать вторую :(
Это можно как-то исправить ???

Comment: @Bernard, она определена внутри первой, вызвать нельзя. Если определить снаружи, то замыкания и, соответственно, переменных не будет.

Comment: @Other, ага окай , спасибо )

Answer (score 1):

Можно определить класс и добавить к нему метод `__call__`

Тогда экземпляр этого класса можно вызвать как функцию, и доступ к своим переменным он тоже будет предоставлять.

```
class First(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = '1'
        self.b = '2'
        self.c = '3'

    def __call__(self):
        print(self.a, self.b, self.c)

first = First()

first()     # Выведет 1, 2, 3

def second():
    lst = []
    lst.append(first.a)
    lst.append(first.b)
    lst.append(first.c)
    return lst

print(second())  # Выведет ['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def first(dt):
    dt.update(a=1, b=2, c=3)
    return dt

def second(dt):
    return list(dt.items())

print(second(first({})))
>>> [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def first():
    global a
    global b
    global c
    a = '1'
    b = '2'
    c = '3'
    print(a,b,c)

def second():
    lst = []
    lst.append(a)
    lst.append(b)
    lst.append(c)
    return lst
first()
print(second())
```

объявите переменные a,b,c глобальными

Comment: использование глобальных переменных лучше избегать. Просто верните желаемые значения из `first()` (используйте `return a, b, c`, а не `print()` как в вопросе) и принимайте переменные явно `second(a, b, c)`, (вместо использования нелокальных переменных как в вопросе).